# ggplot2 split axes conjunctions and add customised labels to them

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm quite getting crazy with a plot.
I'm trying to reproduce axes plotted in this way. Just splitted, in other words regardless of values and other horizontal bars:

[image]

In another post I asked how to do this, and I got a gentle support. Now I'm at this point with the following code:

[image]

> ```
>        ggplot(new_data1, aes(anno, uds_2, color = Hospital)) +
>        geom_point(size = 2, position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.4, jitter.width = 0.5)) +          
>         scale_colour_manual(values=setNames(new_data1[,6],  new_data1[,2])) +             
>         theme_classic() +            
>         labs(x="", y="") +             
>         easy_remove_x_axis() +             
>         easy_remove_y_axis() +
>         theme(legend.position = "none") +               
>         geom_function(fun = function(x) x, color = NA, na.rm = TRUE)  +
>         scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-200, -100, 0, 100, 200), 
>                             limits = c(-250, 250), name = NULL,expand = c(0, 0),
>                             labels = c(-200, -100, 0, 100, 200)) +                
>         scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2014.5, 2019.5),  expand = c(0, 0),
>                             breaks = 2015:2019, name = NULL, labels = c("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019")) + 
>         annotate('segment', x = 2014.5, y = -200, xend = 2014.5, yend = 200, size = 1) +
>         annotate('segment', x = 2015, y = -250, xend = 2019, yend = -250, size = 1)
> ```

Now my point is that the code above does not label the axes.

The original plot without any other manipulation is the following:

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You are removing the axis text, titles, ticks and lines with `ggeasy::easy_remove_x_axis()` and `ggeasy::easy_remove_y_axis()`. Perhaps that's the reason for your issue.

Comment: Yes, this to set new axes otherwise they will overlap

Comment: Are you looking for something [like this](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/PositionGuides.html#truncated-axes)? (Disclaimer: I wrote that function)

Comment: Wow! Just that! That's new to me! Thank u very much!